# deleting a folder in windows requires computer restart

Tags: windows, cmd

After I open a folder in command prompt in windows 10, and after I navigate out of it from command prompt, or even close the command prompt, I cannot delete it if I want to until I restart the computer. It just gives an error stating "This action can't be completed because the folder or file in it is open in other program." I am absolutely certain that it is not open in any of the programs. What do I do? I can't restart every time when I want to delete a file..

Answer (score 0):

Install process explorer from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Go to the menu item Find->Handle or dll
Search in there for what you are deleting. See what comes up. You should ideally be able to see what is retaining a reference (ie handle) to that folder. There's multiple potential causes, including third party libraries.